# Display JSON News Articles using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, json, parsing, feed

Hi I've been accepted for a stage one interview which is a skills test. I was hoping I was going to be given a little longer than I have to get this test sorted but I'm struggling a little!

The brief is as follows.

"The task is to create a simple web app using Backbone.js to fetch, parse and display content from a JSON feed.

Supplied is a file called ‘data.js’. This file contains JSON for eight news stories from Google News. Your task is to create a Backbone web app which will request this file using AJAX, parse the data into individual articles and display a list of each title on the page. Clicking a list item will show an ‘expanded detail’ view displaying the article title and content."

I've gone through countless tutorials but none I've found are showing, or at least easy to adapt to what I need to do.

So far I've linked up the JQuery, Underscore and Backbone libraries. Could anyone be so kind as to share some code that I need, even just to display the news feed directly and I can take it from there and sort out displaying it in the individual articles..

Thankyou,
Dan.